# Achieving texture feedback with THREE.EffectComposer

Tags: three.js, textures

Moving some old effects into alteredq's EffectComposer, and currently unsure of how to achieve texture feedback effects.

In other applications, this is a really straightforward process. I send a signal into a feedback shader (which scales/multiplies/rotates), send the signal out to another effect chain, and then back into the feedback for another pass. This hasn't been this straightforward with Three, but I've managed to make it work by ping-ponging the fbos.

I'm interested in streamlining this by using EffectComposer, but finding it difficult to recreate the effect.

Currently I can conceptualize the use of four composers:

**First**, an input composer that applies effects to the current scene, and renders to a target.

```
this.inputComposer = new THREE.EffectComposer(this.manager.renderer, this.rawTexture);
this.inputComposer.setSize(this.manager.width, this.manager.height);

const inputPass = new THREE.RenderPass(this.manager.scene, this.manager.camera.getCamera());

this.inputComposer.addPass(inputPass);
```

**Second**, a feedback shader that accepts the output from the inputComposer, and also an input from a subsequent effect composer.

```
this.feedbackComposer = new THREE.EffectComposer(this.manager.renderer, this.textureB);
this.feedbackComposer.setSize(this.manager.width, this.manager.height);

this.shader_feedback = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  uniforms: {
    fb: { value: this.textureA.texture },
    feedback: { value: 0.6 },
    scale: { value: 0.992 },
    vPoint: { value: [0.5,0.5] }
  },
  vertexShader: feedback.vert,
  fragmentShader: feedback.frag
})

const inputPass  = new THREE.TexturePass(this.rawTexture.texture, 1.0);
const feedbackPass  = new THREE.ShaderPass(this.shader_feedback, "feedback");

this.feedbackComposer.addPass(inputPass);
this.feedbackComposer.addPass(feedbackPass);
```

**Third**, an intermediate composer, responsible for adding **mid-feedback** shaders. *This should be fed back into the feedback shader.*

```
this.intermediateComposer = new THREE.EffectComposer(this.manager.renderer, this.intermediateTarget);
this.intermediateComposer.setSize(this.manager.width, this.manager.height);

this.shader_sharpen = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  uniforms: {
    width: { value: 0.8 }
  },
  vertexShader: sharpen.vert,
  fragmentShader: sharpen.frag
})

const inputPass  = new THREE.TexturePass(this.textureB.texture, 1.0);
const sharpenPass  = new THREE.ShaderPass(this.shader_sharpen, "sharpen");

this.intermediateComposer.addPass(inputPass);
this.intermediateComposer.addPass(sharpenPass);
```

**Fourth**, a post-feedback output composer, for whatever post effects should be on top of all else.

```
this.finalComposer = new THREE.EffectComposer(this.manager.renderer);
this.finalComposer.setSize(this.manager.width, this.manager.height);

this.shader_chroma = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  uniforms: {
    barrelPower: { value: 0.4 },
    zoom: { value: 1.0 }
  },
  vertexShader: barrelBlurChroma.vert,
  fragmentShader: barrelBlurChroma.frag
})

const inputPass  = new THREE.TexturePass(this.textureC.texture, 1.0);
const chromaPass = new THREE.ShaderPass(this.shader_chroma, "chroma");

chromaPass.renderToScreen = true;

this.finalComposer.addPass(inputPass);
this.finalComposer.addPass(chromaPass);
```

and then **finally**, in render:

```
this.inputComposer.render( delta );
this.feedbackComposer.render(delta);
this.intermediateComposer.render( delta );
this.finalComposer.render( delta );
```

(1) I am not entirely sure whether or not I'm overlooking a more elegant approach.

(2) I can't figure out for the life of me which targets need to be swapped. I know that EffectComposer has swapBuffers(), which does the same, but I'm not entirely sure where to go from here.